# In Flutter, How to detect the completion of copying file?

Tags: flutter

I am beginner on Flutter.

I want to do this process,,,

```
1. save a image file. 
2. read the property information of the saved image file.
```

below is the code for it.

```
// save a image file.
String mainDir = await getMainDirectory(widget.topic);
String path = mainDir + '/' + count.toString();
image.copy(path);

ImageProperties properties;

try {

  // get the property information of the image file.
  properties = await FlutterNativeImage.getImageProperties( path);
}
on PlatformException catch(e) {

  print( e );

  // try again ... 
  properties = await FlutterNativeImage.getImageProperties(
      path);
}
```

When this code running, sometimes an error is occurred. 
the error message is  "file is not exist".

So, I have to call  "getImageProperties()" function again, and I can get the property.

If I can detect the completion of the file copy, I can make these code better.

Is there any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use await to make sure image copy finish

```
final File newImage = await image.copy(path);
```

Comment: It works fine with await keyword.  
Thank you so much !

Comment: Glad to help. please mark this as answer if it help you. thanks.